# Ultrasonic sensor range and shape

Tags: ultrasonic-sensors

I have been looking for a cheap ultrasonic sensor that is not blind under +/-30 cm but the only sensors I could find use the following shape, which is not suitable for my project (because of the robot design that only has 1 hole, and not 2..) : [image: shape 1]

Is there any chance to find a sensor with that other shape with a range starting around 5cm ?

[image: shape 2]

Actually I am wondering if that 2nd shape makes this constraint mandatory or if I just did not found the appropriate product.

Comment: Shopping questions are not allowed on the robotics stackexchange. 
http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: For shorter ranges you could consider an infrared proximity sensor.

Comment: @holmeski It's not a shopping question, my point since the begining was to get an answer that gives an explanation to that finding, and that's exactly what hauptmech did. If that wasn't clear enough, feel free to edit my question as I can't do more as english is not my main language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single transducer sensor has to both send out the sound and then sense the return sound. It takes time for the vibration to stop after making the sound and that is time it can't sense a return. So close distances can't be sensed by a single transducer sensor.